# $p$-norm square equality

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

$${  \| x-y \|_{p}^{2} =^{?}
\| x \|_{p}^{2} 
        -2x^{T}y 
        + \| y\|_{p}^{2}, \; \; \; \; \; \; \;
        p \neq 2, \;
        x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}
}$$

${x}$ is a column vector, ${x^{T}}$ is the transpose of ${x}$ so is a row vector, ${x^{T}y}$ is the inner product between ${x}$ and ${y}$. 
${\| x \|_{p}}$ is the standard Lp-norm as
${ \|x\|_{p} := ({\sum_{i=1}^{d}{ |x_{i}|^{p} }})^{\frac{1}{p}}  }$.

It seems not many people have a question on this equality. It is simple that the equality holds when ${p=2}$ because ${|x_{i}|^{2} = x_{i}^{2}}$. 
But it is already not obvious to me when ${p=1}$ while I'd like to see what happens when ${p \neq 2}$. Could anyone help me to see if this holds or not?

Thanks. And simply giving me a reference is also appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for replies. Particulary, the answer from Maximal is also what I hear from one of my colleagues. Actually then I figure out that my question was not exactly what I wanted. It seems I need to seek for how I define the term in the middle when ${p \neq 2}$ while ${\|x\|_{p}^{2} + \|y\|_{p}^{2} }$ stays the same. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a counterexample, but this might help you to better understand why this particular equation will most likely only hold for the 2-norm.

If your norm $\Vert x \Vert$ is induced by an inner product over the real numbers, ie $\Vert x \Vert = \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle}$, then we have:

$$ \Vert x - y \Vert^2 = \langle x - y, x - y\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle - 2 \langle x, y\rangle + \langle y, y\rangle = \Vert x \Vert^2 - 2 \langle x, y\rangle + \Vert y \Vert^2.$$

As the Euclidean norm is induced by the standard dot-product on $\mathbb{R}^d$, this already implies that the occurrence of $-2x^{T}y$ is linked to this norm and probably does not generalize to other p-norms.

Answer (score 1):

$d=2$, $p=1$, $x^T= (1,1)$ and $y^T= (1,-1)$

$$4=\Vert x-y \Vert_1^2 \neq \Vert x \Vert_1^{2}-2x^{T}y+ \Vert y\Vert_1^{2} = 4-0+4 = 8$$